# Promise in promises array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wrote following code to get all tours of a user. And when getting them I ve updating as follow. Code is perfectly work for parent promises. Tour Status correctly update.. And then I need to get each tour offers count. But the inner promise return null. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

```
const response = await Tour.find({ customer: user.id }).sort({
        createdAt: -1
    });

    const toursPromises = response.map(async tour => {
        if (tour.tourStatus === 'new' && tour.transferDate < Date.now()) {
            return await Tour.findByIdAndUpdate(
                tour._id,
                { $set: { tourStatus: 'expired' } },
                { new: true }
            );
        } else if (tour.tourStatus === 'new') {
            return await Tour.findByIdAndUpdate(
                tour._id,
                {
                    $set: {
                        offers: await Offer.find({
                            tour: tour._id,
                            offerStatus: 'new'
                        }).length
                    }
                },
                { new: true }
            );
        } else {
            return tour;
        }
    });

    const tours = await Promise.all(toursPromises);
```

Comment: where did you get null response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find()` does not return a value with a `length` property, but a promise. So you need to `await` `find()`, not `find().length`. Use parentheses:

```
    (await Offer.find({
        tour: tour._id,
        offerStatus: 'new'
    })).length
```

**Remark:** maybe such mistakes would occur less often if we paid more attention to how we talk about promises. Don't say *"the inner promise **returns** null"*, but: *"the inner promise **resolves** to null"*. Because: promises don't return anything -- they are not functions, but mere objects. These objects change state as they resolve with a value, or reject with a reason.

Comment: thank you so much @trincot.. And I have another q... Using promise in promises, is it bad coding and not good for performance?

Comment: I see no problem there. This promise is actually not *in* the other, as it is resolved before the other (outer) is created. So `Offer.find` is resolved first, and only then execution continues to call `findByIdAndUpdate`, which creates the next promise.

Comment: @Adam passing too many promises into Promise.all is problematic or not?

Comment: @RaghuChahar, does your question have anything to do with my answer? If not, maybe post this comment under the question instead of under my answer?

Comment: @trincot I am sorry I thought i mentioned you. Actually I was asking this to you.

Comment: Then I don't understand your comment. My answer does not concern `Promise.all`, and I have no way to know whether the OP is collecting the right promises to pass to `Promise.all`. I think this question should be for the OP.